# Error: No module named messages Django 1.1.3

Tags: django

I was working on a Django project in version 2.0, but my client was unhappy about it as he wants that project to be made with Django 1.1.3. So, I switched back to old version and tried to setup the project on that version but was unable to do so.

After that, I created a new project in Django 1.1.3 and created a Django app too. I tried to run command `python manage.py syncdb` but I got this error message:

```
Error: No module named messages
```

What's the issue? I am not able to find Django 1.1.3 documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `django.contrib.messages` is available only for Django versions >= 1.2, unfortunately.

You could maybe convince your client to switch to 1.2.X, or write your own messages as part of your server's responses, and create your own client-side message renderer.

Comment: can I use JSONFIELD in django 1.1

Comment: Unfortunately, no (and I did not know that). Please refer to this question you asked a couple of hours ago, and which has a good answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226099/how-to-use-model-jsonfield-in-django-1-1