# how to use model jsonfield in django 1.1

Tags: django

I was working on Django project using django version 2.0 but somehow I switched back to 1.1 because of my client requirements.

I had used jsonfield in my django models in django version 2.0 but when I use this 
same field in django 1.1 it doesn't work. 
Instead it throw error like ImportError: No module named postgres.fields

I tried to use https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield this project as well but it has updated my django to 2.0 again. Is there any way I can use jsonfield in django 1.1

Comment: Do you actually mean 1.1, or 1.11? If it is really 1.1, are your client's requirements "run a horribly insecure and unsafe site that is liable to be hacked at any moment"?

Comment: yes he really wants (1.1) that. What can I do

Comment: You can ignore them. There isn't a sane reason to use 9 years old version in a new project.

Comment: If this is for a client, you should be careful to consider what kind of liability you're opening yourself up to by knowingly developing on an absolutely insecure version of Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with only the Django 1.1 core because `JSONField` was implemented into the Django core in version 1.9. See [Django 1.9 `JSONField` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). However, I believe you could find a solution in this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12990), which includes a lot of links to pre-1.9 `JSONField` implementation.